# What type of a sentence is this?

Tags: types-of-sentences

In grammars, types of sentences are defined as:

**Simple**: a sentence comprised of only one independent clause.

**Compound**: a sentence comprised of minimum two independent clauses.

**Complex**: a sentence comprised of at least one independent clause and one or more dependent clauses.

Then, what type of a sentence is the following?

***The more ignorant a man is, the less modest he is.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The more ignorant a man is, the less modest he is.*

This is a **correlative** comparative construction in which "the more ignorant a man is" is a subordinate (dependent) clause.

The second clause is superordinate.

According to your sentence types, this is thus a complex sentence.

Comment: Should we even call them clauses?  Except for the relative phrases, there are no verbs -- so it is made from subordinate and superordinate fragments.

Comment: What makes the difference: one dependent and the other independent? Both the clauses are equal and keep parallelism in the comparative construction. Does the position of the clause have any role to play in this kind of constructions?

Comment: @mahmudkoya Who says both clauses are equal? What evidence do you have to support that? (Further how can two independent clauses be separated by just a comma?)

Comment: @BillJ, Each clause has a subject, verb and subject complement of its own, and that makes them equal.

Comment: @mahmudkoya The second clause is superordinate: 'man becomes less modest as he becomes more ignorant'. The sentence as a whole is the matrix clause.

Comment: @BillJ ok, now it's clear. *The man becomes less modest*  **as he becomes more ignorant.**

Comment: @mahmudkoya Yes, the dependent (subordinate) clause functions as an adjunct.

Answer (score 0):

Neither portion of the sentence can function as an independent clause on its own:

> ✘ The more ignorant a man is.
>   ✘ The less modest he is.

Since each portion cannot stand on its own, and you cannot have a sentence composed of two dependent clauses, the sentence must be a single independent clause.

In fact, it takes the same essential form as other comparative independent clauses:

> You are smarter than me.
>   The dog is faster than the cat.

Neither of those has a component that can be separated from the rest and be able to stand alone.

If you paraphrase the sentence in question, it actually becomes something like this:

> A man's ignorance is in inverse proportion to his modesty.

The construction that uses a comma makes it appear as if one portion is a dependent clause while the other is an independent clause—but that's not the case.

Since it's a single independent clause, that makes it a simple sentence.

Comment: What about the paraphrase: "If a man is more ignorant then he is less modest." ?

Comment: @amI Although the meaning is the same, it wouldn't be a good example, because *he is less modest* actually is an independent clause. (The same is true of any *if / then* construction, where the *then* portion is an independent clause.)

Comment: But your paraphrase also has an independent clause, while the OP does not.  I am warning that any paraphrase can change the structure to where you can't say that the original sentence must share the same structure.

Comment: @am My paraphrase is a sentence with *only* an independent clause. And the point of my answer is that the original sentence must be an independent clause in its entirety—otherwise it would not be a valid sentence. At least not by the three categories that are given in the question.

Comment: The original is two fragments -- there must be some elision going on.  (I suspect that the elision would be closed class word[s].)

Comment: @aml They are only fragments if you consider them in isolation. But if they are both fragments even when joined—then you're actually saying it's not a technically valid sentence. (Although it could still be acceptable stylistically.) You can't just say that there *must* be elision because only that would make it valid, and you believe it's valid, therefore it must be happening. Occam's razor would say that it's more likely some sentences *can* be technically valid (without regard to stylistic consideration) even with fragments like this. Otherwise—what is an example of the elision at work?

Comment: Sentences are valid because we know how to interpret them.  We know that correlative fragments paired like this mean that one implies the other.  Implication is (at its core) if-then (in my opinion).  What I don't see in your argument is why we should think of them as coding the information of a single clause.  Your paraphrase is too weak an argument for me.

Comment: @aml You should really provide an answer yourself. These comments aren't detailed enough for me to understand your arguments—and they seem sufficiently different from the other answers to warrant separate treatment.